# Is the sum of all rational numbers between two integers infinity

Tags: calculus, integration

If there are infinite numbers between two rational numbers then would that entail that the sum of all numbers, say between 1 and 2, be infinity?

I believe that this cannot be true and has to do something with area under a curve?

Comment: No, you cannot conclude from the fact that there are infinitely many rationals that the sum must be infinite. This is the error behind Zeno's paradox of the Achilles (e.g., $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ is finite, even though you are adding infinitely many positive rational numbers).

Comment: However, the sum is potentially infinite anyway; certainly it is infinite for all rationals between $1$ and $2$, since this includes countably many rationals that are greater than or equal to $1$, so the sum is strictly larger than any positive integer.

Comment: I was just about to type that last comment, @ArturoMagidin. Summing infinitely many numbers greater than $1$ must, almost by definition, be infinite.

Comment: And the rationals between $0$ and $1$ include all rationals of the form $\frac{1}{n}$, and since the harmonic series diverges... so, the answer is that the sum of all rationals between two integers is always infinite, but not for the reason you provide; and the sum of all rationals between any two rationals should also be infinite, verifiable by using a linear transformation to take, say, $[1,2]$ to $[q_1,q_2]$ in a way that maps rationals to rationals, and use it to put lower bounds on the sum.

Comment: You want to get into thorny matters?  Ask whether the sum of all rational numbers between $-1$ and $1$ is infinite.

Comment: It seems you are confusing the "simple" sum with the Riemann sum: the difference is the multiplication by the term  $\Delta x$, with that the sum becomes finite.

Comment: "has to do something with area under a curve".  Careful.  The area under a curve is $\int_1^2 r(t) dt = \lim_{\Delta t\to 0} \sum [r(t)*\Delta t]$ but you are asking what is $\sum [r(t)]$  and $\Delta t \ne 1$.  The area under a curve is a sum of rectangles with "teeeeeeny" basis. A sum is a sum of values.  To view them as "rectangles" the must have *unit* bases.

Comment: Regarding your comment on area under a curve, while this sum is infinite/diverges, if you integrate the indicator function of the rationals (a function that is 1 at any rational number, 0 at all others), you will get 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can answer this question you need a definition for what it means to "add up infinitely many numbers".

For the moment, assume those numbers are listed in some order:
$$
a_1, a_2, \ldots .
$$
Then mathematicians define the infinite sum to be the *limit* (if it exists) of the numbers
$$
a_1,  \quad  a_1 +  a_2, \quad  a_1 +  a_2 + a_3,  \ldots .
$$
Then, for example, you could show that the "infinite sum"
$$
1 +
\frac{1}{2} +
\frac{1}{4} +
\frac{1}{8} + \cdots
$$
is $2$. So sometimes the sum of infinitely many numbers is finite.

With that definition, you clearly can't sum all the rational numbers between $1$ and $2$ since all of them are greater than $1$, so those partial sums will grow without bound. You can't sum all the rational numbers between $0$ and $0.0001$ since infinitely many of them are greater than $0.00001$. So you are more or less correct - mathematicians prefer to say you can't sum them, not that the sum is infinity.

When you learn calculus (that "something with area under a curve") you will see how to add up more and more and more pieces without growing to infinity because at each stage the pieces are smaller and smaller and smaller.

Comment: "You can't sum all the numbers between [...]" See that OP asks for all the rational numbers. It doesn't seems obvious to me that your proof holds...

Comment: @rafa11111 There are infinitely many rational numbers in the interval that are larger than the midpoint. I edited the answer.

Comment: Typo: $1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots = 2$, not $1$.

Comment: @BrianTung I fixed it thanks. You could have.

Comment: @EthanBolker: I know.  I like to allow the answerer to fix it first in the way they think best.  If you hadn't come back to fix it, I'd have done it eventually.

Comment: Food for thought though.  What about summing in an interval with negative numbers.  $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: "You could have."  I, personally, feel very uncomfortable editting other peoples math.  I'm okay with typos and formatting.  I'd be okay with correcting arithmetic but I don't want to presume I should be correcting their interpretations or arguments. Frankly I find such editings .... rude.  (And there are plenty of cases where people *badly* misunderstood what the OP meant and "fixed" it to the point of complete botching)